# Authenticate Airflow APIs using Okta or OAuth2

Tags: api, authentication, oauth-2.0, airflow, okta

I want to know if we can secure calls to Airflow APIs using Okta or OAuth2.

Example: `curl -H "**Authorization: Bearer <okta_jwt_token**>" https://airflow//api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/tasks/<TASK_ID>`

Searching in the documentation, Airflow provides basic or kerberos authentication mode but not other like Okta or OAuth2.

Thanks a lot for your help.

**Configure Airflow with OAuth2**

```
curl -H "**Authorization: Bearer <okta_jwt_token**>" https://airflow//api/experimental/dags/<DAG_ID>/tasks/<TASK_ID>
```